# Why do we need more voltage levels to drive a dynamic multiplexed LCD?

Tags: lcd

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN3412.pdf

Dynamically driven LCDs require more than two voltage levels to drive segments. The different voltage levels to drive a dynamic
LCD must be at least 0, 1.6, and 3 volts, so the required voltage levels are generated with external resistors. The voltage levels
are called bias, in this case ½ bias. To turn any segment on, the voltage applied between the desired frontplane terminal and the
appropriate backplane must be 3 volts. To turn any segment off, the voltage level applied between the frontplane and backplane
terminal must not be higher than 1.6 volts.

Comment: the voltage across a segment cannot have a DC component or the LCD segment may be damaged ... the positives must match the negatives over time

Comment: LCDs need a noise free bias voltage to properly control the contrast and darkness